# What does 'value' mean when nnet() is iterating in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm running a neural net with the nnet package in R.

```
nn1=nnet(as.factor(label)~.,data=train,maxit=1000,MaxNWts=10000,size=10)
# weights:  7960
initial  value 81335.408815 
iter  10 value 38857.459601
iter  20 value 33975.310248
iter  30 value 30937.917898
```

I'm wondering if someone can explain what 'value' refers to, and whether there is a way to initialize it manually.

Thanks!!

Comment: It you carefully read `?nnet`, you will find the answer to your question.

Comment: The description lists this as "value of fitting criterion plus weight decay term." 
Is there a more intuitive explanation to this?
Thanks!

Comment: And how about searching this on Internet?

Comment: You'd do best if you dug into the literature cited for this particular package.